# Сгруппировать в списки непрерывные подпоследовательности чисел

Tags: python, list, многомерные-списки

Дан список:
list1 = [1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 10]

Необходимо разбить его и получить:
list2 = [[1,2], [6], [8, 9, 10]] или [[1,2], [8, 9, 10]]

Критерий:
Сгруппировать в списки непрерывные подпоследовательности чисел исходной последовательности (списка)

Моё решение:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 10]
count = 0
list2 = [set()]
for index in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[index] - list1[index - 1] == 1:
        list2[count].add(list1[index])
        list2[count].add(list1[index - 1])
    else:
        count += 1
        list2.append(set())
list2 = list(map(list, filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, list2)))
print(list2) # [[1, 2], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: У вас были какие-то попытки решить данную задачу ? Есть пример вашего кода ? Если вы просто решили сюда вкинуть условия задачи что-бы за вас решили, то вам проще идти в google искать.

Comment: если не хотите чтобы ваш вопрос был закрыт и если хотите чтобы вам помогли, покажите свой код и поясните с чем у вас возникли трудности.

Comment: В одну строчку - `list2 = [list(sum(g,())[1::2]) for _,g in __import__("itertools").groupby(enumerate(list1), key=lambda x: x[1]-x[0])]`

Comment: @GrAnd при том, что код работает, я в голове не могу это представить :)

Comment: @splash58 Да вроде ничего особо сложного здесь нет... `groupby()` из-за `enumerate()` идёт по кортежам (индекс, значение). Ключевая функция для `groupby` - это разница между индексом и значением, и эта разница постоянна для последовательных элементов (индекс растёт на единицу, и значение на единицу). Соответственно `groupby` соберёт группы из последовательных элементов. Ну а всякие `list(sum(...))` - это чтобы оставить только значения, т.к. после `groupby` там будут кортежи (индекс, значение), а индекс нам не интересен. Можно было там использовать `list(map(lambda x: x[1], g))` как вариант.

Comment: @GrAnd да, спасибо разобрался. не пользовался groupby, поэтому не сразу представил, что она вернет

Answer (score 1):

Создайте список из одного списка из первого числа. Далее цикл: если новое число на единицу больше последнего числа в последнем списке, то добавим его в последний список, иначе добавим новый список с этим числом:

```
def split(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    try:
        groups = [[next(it)]]
    except StopIteration:
        return []
    for n in it:
        if n == groups[-1][-1] + 1:
            groups[-1].append(n)
        else:
            groups.append([n])
    return groups


print(split([1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 10]))
```

> ```
> python split.py
> [[1, 2], [6], [8, 9, 10]]
> ```